# Passing multiple optionnal params to a route

Tags: php, laravel

I'm preparing the backend for my axios request. The front looks like this

```
handleSearchSubmit(column, value, dateFrom, dateTo) {
            axios
            .get(`api/analyses/get_requested_analysis/${column}/${value}/${dateFrom}/${dateTo}`, {
                column,
                value,
                dateFrom,
                dateTo
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            })
        },
```

So the user will a select a field (column) (a line in my DB) and a value for me to search. Sometimes the user will input a string, or sometimes dates.

The route looks like this :

```
Route::get('/analyses/get_requested_analysis/{column}/{value?}/{dateFrom?}/{dateTo?}', 'Api\AnalyseController@get_requested_analysis')
```

The problem i have right now is if the user wants to search by dates i end up with

```
/analyses/get_requested_analysis/Date//2021-09-29/2021-10-08 404 (Not Found)
```

With two // since the value isn't present.

Any idea how to solve this ? Or how to group my params so the Route isn't so 'weird' ? something like '/get_requested_analysis' with params in the controller and not in the route url.

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and i'm quite lost because i've never studied php

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use the request parameter to send the data instead?

Comment: Oh yeah that's a good idea, my bad. And then use Request $request in my controller ?

Comment: yes, that way you don't have to hard code the route

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot ! I'll try that then

Comment: I figured it out for those wondering, has() is only going to work if the axios request is set to be url, {params:{}}, otherwise it ends up in config !

Answer (score 0):

I think that using everything in the route is not efficient, you should just use regular get params :

```
/analyses/get_requested_analysis/{column}?value=foo,from=2021-10-08,to=2021-10-09
```

if you want to add additionnal verification on the date format, you can do that in your controller :

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'from' => 'date_format:Y-m-d',
    'to' => 'date_format:Y-m-d'
]);
```

so that you are sure that values passed in the url are in the desired format